# R regular expression: how to extract elements that contains two character in a certain order?

Tags: r, regex, text

I'm trying to use regular expression to extract certain elements from a vector of characters. For example, I want to extract all elements that contains the characters `'abc'` and `'5'` in that order. There can be characters before `'abc'`, in between `'abc'` and `'5'`, and after `'5'`

This is what I've come up with before. I'm using . to indicate anything (or nothing).

```
testvec = c('abc5', 'bc5', 'abc', 'aaabc3fs55')
grepl('.abc.5.', testvec, value = TRUE)
```

The correct answer should be

```
'abc5',   'aaabc3fs55'
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep('abc.*5', testvec, value = TRUE)
# [1] "abc5"       "aaabc3fs55"
```

Meanwhile your `.abc.5.` means: any single symbol, abc, any single symbol, 5, any single symbol.

With `abc.*5` I specified that there can be multiple characters in between abc and 5, and it's not necessary (in your case) to say anything about what happens after and before them; i.e., there are no constraints, `grep` is simply looking for `abc.*5` somewhere in the elements of `testvec`.